# squid 3.5 https setup ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, squid

I wonder if some one would be able to help me solve a squid issue. I am attempting to setup squid on ubuntu 16.04. I used apt-get install to install it. and I have version 3.5.

I can't seem to get the https side of things working. I have a single server, with one nic. I have setup ip table rules and I can get the port 80 stuff working properly if I strip out the ssl stuff...

The Iptables rules I have is :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3129
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3130
```

The error I can't seem to get around is:

```
    systemctl status squid
● squid.service - LSB: Squid HTTP Proxy version 3.x
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/squid; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2017-09-06 15:24:58 UTC; 3s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 31100 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/squid stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31116 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/squid start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 06 15:24:58 ip-10-10-0-184 squid[31116]: 2017/09/06 15:24:58| WARNING: You should probably remove '10.10.8.0/24' from the ACL
Sep 06 15:24:58 ip-10-10-0-184 squid[31116]: 2017/09/06 15:24:58| FATAL: Invalid ACL type 'ssl::server_name'
Sep 06 15:24:58 ip-10-10-0-184 squid[31158]: Bungled /etc/squid/squid.conf line 73: acl allowed_https_sites ssl::server_name .ubu
Sep 06 15:24:58 ip-10-10-0-184 squid[31116]: FATAL: Bungled /etc/squid/squid.conf line 73: acl allowed_https_sites ssl::server_na
Sep 06 15:24:58 ip-10-10-0-184 squid[31116]: Squid Cache (Version 3.5.12): Terminated abnormally.
Sep 06 15:24:58 ip-10-10-0-184 squid[31116]: CPU Usage: 0.004 seconds = 0.004 user + 0.000 sys
Sep 06 15:24:58 ip-10-10-0-184 squid[31116]: Maximum Resident Size: 46928 KB
Sep 06 15:24:58 ip-10-10-0-184 squid[31116]: Page faults with physical i/o: 0
Sep 06 15:24:58 ip-10-10-0-184 squid[31116]:    ...fail!
Sep 06 15:24:58 ip-10-10-0-184 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Squid HTTP Proxy version 3.x.
```

The conf file looks like this:

```
    #Anonomize proxi connections

forwarded_for off
request_header_access Allow allow all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
request_header_access Content-Type allow all
request_header_access Date allow all
request_header_access Expires allow all
request_header_access Host allow all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
request_header_access Last-Modified allow all
request_header_access Location allow all
request_header_access Pragma allow all
request_header_access Accept allow all
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
request_header_access Content-Language allow all
request_header_access Mime-Version allow all
request_header_access Retry-After allow all
request_header_access Title allow all
request_header_access Connection allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Connection allow all
request_header_access User-Agent allow all
request_header_access Cookie allow all
request_header_access All deny all

visible_hostname gw.fairsquare.com

#ACL definitions
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 'this' network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8         # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10      # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localhet src 169.254.0.0/16     # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 10.10.5.0/24       # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.10.6.0/24       # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.10.7.0/24       # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.10.8.0/24       # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7           # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10          # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access allow localnet
http_access allow Safe_ports

refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320

#Handling HTTPS requests
https_port 3130 cert=/etc/squid/ssl/squid.pem ssl-bump intercept
acl SSL_port port 443
http_access allow SSL_port
acl allowed_https_sites ssl::server_name .ubuntu.com
acl allowed_https_sites ssl::server_name .amazon.com
#acl allowed_https_sites ssl::server_name [you can add other domains to permit]
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
acl step2 at_step SslBump2
acl step3 at_step SslBump3
ssl_bump peek step1 all
ssl_bump peek step2 allowed_https_sites
ssl_bump splice step3 allowed_https_sites
ssl_bump terminate step2 all

#Handling HTTP requests
http_port 3129 intercept
acl allowed_http_sites dstdomain .amazonaws.com
acl allowed_http_sites dstdomain .amazon.com
acl allowed_http_sites dstdomain .ubuntu.com
#acl allowed_http_sites dstdomain [you can add other domains to permit]
http_access allow allowed_http_sites

via off
forwarded_for off
http_access deny all
```

I attempting to find samples of config, which I pieced together... Just want to have an access list to allow ssl sites to go out.

Can someone point out my mistake as I am not sure what is wrong with this ssl name thingy...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Open your file:

```
nano /etc/squid3/squid.conf
```

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>, then type "server_name" and replace server_name by your server name.

```
acl allowed_https_sites ssl::**server_name** .ubuntu.com
acl allowed_https_sites ssl::**server_name** .amazon.com
```

I don't know why but you also have a problem for the network 10.10.8.0/24, so, if you are not using it, you should probably remove `10.10.8.0/24` from the ACL list.

Comment: I found that [the official document](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/) said `the ssl::server_name type to control which server name to match against.`. So I didn't understand what "ssl::**server_name**" means. Is it something different with other OSs? Am I missing something?